# DRF: Custom field error message

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

While creating simple login api using DRF, I encountered a problem. Two field `email` and `password` are required to login. If the fields are left blank following `json` message is shown:

```
{
    "email": [
        "This field may not be blank."
    ],
    "password": [
        "This field may not be blank."
    ]
}
```

But I would like to customise the error message, say to something like,

```
{
    "email": [
        "Email field may not be blank."
    ],
    "password": [
        "Password field may not be blank."
    ]
}
```

I tried the something like the following in `validate()` in `serializers.py` :

```
if email is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'An email address is required to log in.'
            )
```

But it is not getting `override`, I'm not sure about the reason.

**Edit**

I implemented with @dima answer it still not work. What am I doing wrong?, now my serializer looks like:

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=True, error_messages={"required": "Email field may not be blank."})
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, read_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, write_only=True, required=True,
        error_messages={"required": "Password field may not be blank."})
    token = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, read_only=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        # The `validate` method is where we make sure that the current
        # instance of `LoginSerializer` has "valid". In the case of logging a
        # user in, this means validating that they've provided an email
        # and password and that this combination matches one of the users in
        # our database.
        email = data.get('email', None)
        password = data.get('password', None)
        user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)

        # If no user was found matching this email/password combination then
        # `authenticate` will return `None`. Raise an exception in this case.
        if user is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'A user with this email and password was not found.'
            )

        # Django provides a flag on our `User` model called `is_active`. The
        # purpose of this flag is to tell us whether the user has been banned
        # or deactivated. This will almost never be the case, but
        # it is worth checking. Raise an exception in this case.
        if not user.is_active:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'This user has been deactivated.'
            )

        # The `validate` method should return a dictionary of validated data.
        # This is the data that is passed to the `create` and `update` methods
        # that we will see later on.
        return {
            'email': user.email,
            'username': user.username,
            'token': user.token
        }
```

**views.py**

```
class AuthLogin(APIView):
    ''' Manual implementation of login method '''

    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            new_data = serializer.data
            return Response(new_data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set [error_messages](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#error_messages) attribute for fields you want to override message. In your case:

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=True, error_messages={"required": "Email field may not be blank."})
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, read_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, write_only=True, required=True, error_messages={"required": "Password field may not be blank."})
    token = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, read_only=True)
```

For `ModelSerializers` you can do this using [extra_kwargs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments) property in Meta class.

```
class SomeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {"error_messages": {"required": "Password field may not be blank."}},
            'email': {"error_messages": {"required": "Email field may not be blank."}},
        }
```

Comment: I have made an edit to the post and now my `serializer` looks as above. Did as you suggested, not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help

Comment: I edited my answer, it doesn't work because you use `Serializer` instead of `ModelSerializer`

Comment: It works for me, can you update question with latest changes?

Comment: I used your LoginSerializer from your question and it works fine. Can you also add your View maybe you override something in it?

Comment: Added `views.py` file.

Comment: Why you use `raise_exception` flag in `is_valid` method? It should raise exception but you don't catch it in your view

Comment: I use `raise_exception` flag to raise a `serializers.ValidationError` exception if there are validation errors.
These exceptions are handled by default handlers, I guess, as mentioned [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#raising-an-exception-on-invalid-data)

Comment: It's not needed if you check `is_valid` in if statement, I don't know why this doesn't work for you

Comment: Could I get to see your code? Maybe Github link or something.

Comment: I simply made django app with default settings, copied your serializer code and opened django shell where I test serializer with this command: `s=LoginSerializer(data={});s.is_valid();print(s.errors)`

Answer (score 2):

you need [field-level-validation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation), try it:

```
def validate_email(self, value):
#           ^^^^^^
    if not value:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
            'An email address is required to log in.'
        )
    return value
```